# perl magic symbols -w -r and _

Tags: perl

What does this mean in perl ?

```
my $dirPath = "/some/dir"
if (-d $dir_path && -r _ && -w _ )
{

}
```

I know what -d does but what about -w and -r and _ ?

Comment: See [File test operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

```
-r  File is readable by effective uid/gid.
-w  File is writable by effective uid/gid.
```

So `-r` and `-w` test if the file is readable. The underscore is a special handle that is used to ask perl to return information about the file specified in the most recent file test, which is `-d $dir_path` in this case.

So your code tests whether `$dir_path` is a directory for which we have read & write permissions.